# Как привязать к строчкам ListBox свои данные?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как привязать к строчкам `ListBox` свои данные? Например, какой-нить свой *класс* `DataRec`?

Comment: `ListBox` - компонент, предназначенный для отображения коллекции/списка объектов (как понятно из его названия). Вам нужно один экземпляр своего класса привязать или всё же коллекцию?

Comment: Для работы с одним экземпляром посмотрите в сторону `PropertyGrid`.

Answer (score 1):

как-то так:

```
List<DataRec> records = new List<DataRec>();

ListBoxInstanceName.DataSource = records;
```

Comment: Как добавлять теперь данные?

Comment: просто апдейтишь твой List<DataRec> records

Comment: чето у меня так не работает

Comment: @sitev_ru - _чето у меня так не работает_ - я давно считаю, что за такую фразу следует отлучать от мира программирования. Нет в программировании понятия "не работает". Опишите **точную** проблему. Код не компилируется? Компилируется, но не запускается? Запускается, но падает с ошибкой (какой именно)? Исключения нет, но код выдаёт неправильный результат? Какой именно результат? А какой должен быть?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего использовать [BindingSource](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.7.2). У него есть ряд полезных свойств и методов. Например в свойстве `Current` будет выбранный элемент в списке или датагридвью. Использовать можно так

```
private BindingSource _bsPeople = new BindingSource();

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //привязки
    SetBindings();
    //загрузка данных
    LoadData();
}

/// <summary>
/// Установка привязок
/// </summary>
private void SetBindings()
{
    _bsPeople.DataSource = typeof(List<Person>);
    listBoxPeople.DataSource = _bsPeople;
}

/// <summary>
/// Загрузка данных
/// </summary>
private void LoadData()
{
    //получаем список людей из БД
    List<Person> people = Program.Context.GetPeople();

    _bsPeople.Clear();
    people.ForEach(p => _bsPeople.Add(p));
}
```